# Automation Error Unspecified Error with Internet Explorer Object Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working with some code for a while and literally, all of the sudden it broke on me. Here is the error message I'm getting:

```
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)'
Automation error
Unspecified error
```

the line of code is specifically when instantiating an InternetExporer object, except I have done nothing to change the code. It just stopped working. What could be the issue?

This has happened before and I corrected it by explicitly calling the library (MSHTML for a HTMLBsaeObject before), except I'm using just an Object when naming the variables

```
Public Sub ValueLineResearch()

    setUp
    Dim myFund As String

    loginN = Sheets("Logins").Range("B2").Text
    pwStr = Sheets("Logins").Range("B3").Text

    'Get the site
    iEx.Navigate "https://jump.valueline.com/login.aspx"
    iEx.Visible = True

    Call waitForIE

    'Need to login now don't we
    iEx.Document.forms("aspnetForm").Item("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_LoginControl_txtUserID").Value = loginN
    iEx.Document.forms("aspnetForm").Item("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_LoginControl_txtUserPw").Value = pwStr
    iEx.Document.forms("aspnetForm").Item("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_LoginControl_btnLogin").Click

    Call waitForIE
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 6, Now)

    iEx.Navigate "https://research.valueline.com/secure/research#sec=library"

    Call waitForIE

    For Each el1 In iEx.Document.getElementsByClassName("symbol-search textInput ui-autocomplete-input mod_search-symbols primary_symbol_search")
        el1.Value = fundToResearch
    Next

    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)

    iEx.Document.forms("quoteSearch").submit

    Call waitForIE
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)

    iEx.Navigate "https://research.valueline.com/secure/research#list=recent&sec=company&sym=" & fundToResearch

    Call waitForIE

    'store the Doc
    Set ieDoc = iEx.Document

    'For linkItem = 0 To ieDoc.Links.Length - 1
    '    'Get the PDF
    '    If InStr(1, ieDoc.Links(linkItem).href, ".pdf", vbTextCompare) > 0 And InStr(1, ieDoc.Links(linkItem).href, "UserGuide", vbTextCompare) <= 0 Then
    '        ieDoc.Links(linkItem).Click
    '        iEx.Visible = True
    '        Exit For
    '    End If
    'Next linkItem

    Set iEx = Nothing    

End Sub
```

And the setup sub is this:

```
set iEx = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
fundToResarch = LCase(InputBox("Please Enter a Fund"))
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've had a similar problem getting the 'Automation Error' creating an instance of InternetExplorer within a function that is called multiple times. It works fine to start, but after a number of calls will crash with the automation error. I discovered that I had multiple IE processes in memory, which means that setting `objIE = Nothing` is insufficient to remove the process from memory. The solution is to call the 'Quit' method before setting objIE to Nothing.

That is:

```
objIE.Quit

'Put in a brief pause

set objIE = Nothing
```

Comment: I have since moved all of my web scraping for this sheet into C# but I'm definitely keeping this in mind for the future! I had just assumed setting the object to null was closing it, but didn't realize that it wasn't closing the invisible window.

Answer (score 0):

For others who end up here with the same error...

This can also be caused by referencing the `Document` object property in an `InternetExplorer` object after quitting and setting it to nothing. Note that this is not what is happening in the question. I was able to replicate the error with code similar to this:

```
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate "google.com"

ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing

If ie.Document Is Nothing Then 'Error thrown here
    MsgBox "Can't get here"
End If
```